# Проблема с arcticmodal или с JQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Привет, у меня проблема. Есть окно, которая открывается с помощью команды:

```
onclick="$('#atn_win').arcticmodal()"
```

Сначала всё работало прекрасно, потом я обновил JQuery, добавил UI по новей. И всё перестало работать. Консоль браузера говорит, что:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function
at init.run (vendor.js:2788)
at f (vendor.js:775)
at Function.n.fx.timer (vendor.js:2921)
at Xa (vendor.js:804)
at HTMLDivElement.u (vendor.js:2859)
at Function.dequeue (vendor.js:2184)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (vendor.js:2199)
at Function.each (vendor.js:1033)
at n.fn.init.each (vendor.js:946)
at n.fn.init.queue (vendor.js:2197)
```

Я видел решение на форуме, чтобы обновить UI, но не помогает.. Может проблема в самом arcticmodal?

Вот что у меня присоединено к скрипту:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/scripts/tabs.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/scripts/arcticmodal.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
```

Comment: может не стоило плагину 5летней давности подключать jquery 3.2 ?

Comment: @teran Подключил 1.10.2, 1.8.3 - не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, у меня подгружался vendor, с другого сайта, заменил на свой, и всё встало на свои места)

P.S: Jquery можно использовать любой.